# How do I get equal width in jQuery that is responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set the width of one item to match the width of another item. This part of my jQuery is working, but what isn't working is the width adjusting when the viewport is resized. What I have is the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Width Adjustment for Back Item
    $('.hpadvantageitem_back').css({ width : ($('.hpadvantageitem_front').width() + 64) });
    $('.hpextrainfoitem_back').css({ width : ($('.hpextrainfoitem_front').width() + 64) });
});

jQuery(window).load(function($) {

    // Width Adjustment for Back Item
    $('.hpadvantageitem_back').css({ width : ($('.hpadvantageitem_front').width() + 64) });
    $('.hpextrainfoitem_back').css({ width : ($('.hpextrainfoitem_front').width() + 64) });
});

jQuery(window).resize(function($){

    // Width Adjustment for Back Item
    $('.hpadvantageitem_back').css({ width : ($('.hpadvantageitem_front').width() + 64) });
    $('.hpextrainfoitem_back').css({ width : ($('.hpextrainfoitem_front').width() + 64) });
})
```

The document ready and window load functions seem to be working, but not the window resize function. The reason I have to set equal width is because the primary element, `hpadvantageitem_front` has position: relative, whereas `hpadvantageitem_back` has position: absolute. The parent of both containers has position: relative as well, for the `hpadvantageitem_back` item so that it would stay inside the parent container. The issue for why `hpadvantageitem_back` cannot just have width: 100% added is because its width exceeds the width of the parent for some odd reason, even though it shouldn't.

The quick and dirty solution is to add some JavaScript to force `hpadvantageitem_back` to have the same width as `hpadvantageitem_front`, and I can call it a day.

Would someone be so kind and help me with how to make `hpadvantageitem_back` adjust it's width responsively?

If you feel that HTML and CSS is needed, let me know and I'll post it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would be easier if you can create a http://jsfiddle.net with css html

Comment: I'm very sorry everyone. I was beating my head on this issue trying to figure out what was wrong with my JS all to discover it was not firing because of another script running in the site. Please disregard this question. My above jQuery works now that my other problem is solved.

@Sam Battat, thanks for your time, and have a wonderful evening.